# How can I calculate the number of "quarters" that have passed between 2 dates, where quarters are not simply a quarter of a year, but specific dates?

Tags: javascript, date, if-statement, logic, calculator

I am trying to make a "Rent Arrears Calculator" using Javascript, and one of the desired functions is to have the option of calculating rent per week, per month or per quarter.

If rent is payable quarterly, the number of quarters late will increase when the date passes a certain day. These quarter days are 25/03, 24/06, 29/09/ and 25/12 every year.

My code at the moment returns the incorrect value when the month of the input date is greater than the month of a quarter date, but its Date is less than the date of the quarter.

i.e. for a "First missed payment date" of 24/06/2014, and a date of 22/04/2015, this should return 4, but instead returns 1. It should return 4 since 4 quarter dates have been passed in this time (24/06/2014, 29/09/2014, 25/12/2014, and 25/03/2015).

Here is my code:

```
function getNumberPeriods() {
        var years = (getNumberYears());
        var days = (getNumberDays());
        if ((getPeriodLength()) == "Weekly") {
            return ((days - (days % 7)) / 7);
        } else if ((getPeriodLength()) == "Monthly") {
            var months = ((((options.untilDate).getMonth()) + 1) - (((options.dueDate).getMonth()) + 1) + (12 * years));
            if (((options.untilDate).getDate()) < ((options.dueDate).getDate())) {
                months--;
            }
            return (months + 1);
        } else if ((getPeriodLength()) == "Quarterly") {
            if ((options.dueDate).getMonth() == 2) {
                if (((options.untilDate).getMonth() <= 5) && ((options.untilDate).getDate() < 24)) {
                    return (1+(years * 4));
                }
                else if (((options.untilDate).getMonth() <= 5) && ((options.untilDate).getDate() >= 24)) {
                    return (2+(years * 4));
                }
                else if (((options.untilDate).getMonth() <= 8) && ((options.untilDate).getDate() < 29)) {
                    return (2 + (years * 4));
                }
                else if (((options.untilDate).getMonth() <= 8) && ((options.untilDate).getDate() >= 29)) {
                    return (3 + (years * 4));
                }
                else if (((options.untilDate).getMonth() <= 11) && ((options.untilDate).getDate() < 25)) {
                    return (3 + (years * 4));
                }
                else if (((options.untilDate).getMonth() <= 11) && ((options.untilDate).getDate() >= 25)) {
                    return ((years * 4)+4);
                }
                else return (years * 4);
            }
            else if ((options.dueDate).getMonth() == 5) {
                if ((options.untilDate).getMonth() <= 2 && (options.untilDate).getDate() < 25) {
                    return (3 + (years * 4));
                }
                else if ((options.untilDate).getMonth() <= 2 && (options.untilDate).getDate() >= 25) {
                    return (4+(years * 4));
                }
                else if ((options.untilDate).getMonth() <= 8 && (options.untilDate).getDate() < 29) {
                    return ((years * 4)+1);
                }
                else if ((options.untilDate).getMonth() <= 8 && (options.untilDate).getDate() >= 29) {
                    return ((years * 4)+2);
                }
                else if ((options.untilDate).getMonth() <= 11 && (options.untilDate).getDate() < 25) {
                    return (2 + (years * 4));
                }
                else if ((options.untilDate).getMonth() <= 11 && (options.untilDate).getDate() >= 25) {
                    return (3 + (years * 4));
                }
                else return (years * 4);
            }
            else if ((options.dueDate).getMonth() == 8) {
                if ((options.untilDate).getMonth() <= 2 && (options.untilDate).getDate() < 25) {
                    return (2 + (years * 4));
                }
                if ((options.untilDate).getMonth() <= 2 && (options.untilDate).getDate() >= 25) {
                    return (3 + (years * 4));
                }
                else if ((options.untilDate).getMonth() <= 5 && (options.untilDate).getDate() < 24) {
                    return (3 + (years * 4));
                }
                else if ((options.untilDate).getMonth() <= 5 && (options.untilDate).getDate() >= 24) {
                    return (4+(years * 4));
                }
                else if ((options.untilDate).getMonth() <= 11 && (options.untilDate).getDate() < 25) {
                    return ((years * 4)+1);
                }
                else if ((options.untilDate).getMonth() <= 11 && (options.untilDate).getDate() >= 25) {
                    return ((years * 4)+2);
                }
                else return (years * 4);
            }
            else if ((options.dueDate).getMonth() == 11) {
                if ((options.untilDate).getMonth() <= 2 && (options.untilDate).getDate() < 25) {
                    return ((years * 4)+1);
                }
                else if ((options.untilDate).getMonth() <= 2 && (options.untilDate).getDate() >= 25) {
                    return ((years * 4)+2);
                }
                else if ((options.untilDate).getMonth() <= 5 && (options.untilDate).getDate() < 24) {
                    return (2 + (years * 4));
                }
                else if ((options.untilDate).getMonth() <= 5 && (options.untilDate).getDate() >= 24) {
                    return (3 + (years * 4));
                }
                else if ((options.untilDate).getMonth() <= 8 && (options.untilDate).getDate() < 29) {
                    return (3 + (years * 4));
                }
                else if ((options.untilDate).getMonth() <= 8 && (options.untilDate).getDate() >= 29) {
                    return ((years * 4)+4);
                }
                else return (years * 4);
            }
            else alert("not werkin");
        }
    }


    function getNumberDays() {
        return ((((options.untilDate)) - ((options.dueDate))) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    }
    function getNumberYears() {
        var dueMonth = (options.dueDate).getMonth();
        var dueDay = (options.dueDate).getDate();
        var dueYear = (options.dueDate).getFullYear();
        var untilYear = (options.untilDate).getFullYear();
        var untilMonth = (options.untilDate).getMonth();
        var untilDay = (options.untilDate).getDate();
        var diffyears = untilYear - dueYear; 

        if (untilMonth < dueMonth - 1){
         diffyears--;
            }
        if (dueMonth - 1 == untilMonth && untilDay < dueDay){
        diffyears--;
            }
        return diffyears;
```

And [this](https://jsfiddle.net/ezjp20/ak5hexnx/71/) is a link to my JS fiddle (I'm aware that other part of the fiddle aren't working correctly yet I just haven't got to those yet).

Any help would be very greatly appreciated!

Zehra.

Comment: In other words, you need to calculate the number of dates from the `(25/03, 24/06, 29/09/, 25/12 )` set in a given period of time, is it correct?

Comment: yes! that is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you are trying to cover up all of the cases there might be. It is not a very good approach for this problem (and the majority of other problems with large number of cases). Instead, try to think in a different way: you can loop through the quarter dates and see if they are in the period between `dueDate` and `untilDate`. However, you are missing the `year` component of the date to do that. I suggest to use the `dueDate`'s year to construct `Date` objects in the beginning and then increase the year with each iteration, until `year` becomes greater than `untilDate`'s year.

Here is the code listing:

```
     } else if ((getPeriodLength()) == "Quarterly") {
        // We have an array of all the quarter dates
        var quarterDates = [
            {
                'm': 3,
                'd': 25
            },
            {
                'm': 6,
                'd': 24
            },
            {
                'm': 9,
                'd': 29
            },
            {
                'm': 12,
                'd': 25
            }];
        // The count of missed periods
        var count = 0;
        // Initial year value
        var year = options.dueDate.getFullYear();
        // Condition on when to stop
        while (year <= options.untilDate.getFullYear()) {
            for(var i in quarterDates) {
                // Just a precaution, because foreach in js
                // loops through all properties of the object
                // and there might be functions and we want to
                // skip them   
                if (typeof(quarterDates[i]) != 'function') {
                    // Construct a Date object
                    // Note: months in js have numbers from 0 to 11
                    var qDate = new Date(year, quarterDates[i].m - 1, quarterDates[i].d);
                    // If the date is in the given period
                    if (qDate >= options.dueDate && qDate <= options.untilDate) {
                        // Increase the counter
                        count++;
                    }
                }
            }
            // Increase the value
            year++;
        }
        return count;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The following code counts the passed quarters into `passed`

```
var quarters = [{'month':3, 'day':25}, {'month':6, 'day':24}, 
    {'month':9, 'day':29}, {'month':12, 'day':25}];

var year = options.dueDate.getFullYear();
var passed = 0; // this is the number of passed quarters
var quarterIndex = 0;
do {
    // month is 0 based
    var reference = new Date(
        year, 
        quarters[quarterIndex].month - 1, 
        quarters[quarterIndex].day);

    if( (reference >= options.dueDate) && (reference <= options.untilDate) ) {
        passed ++;
    }

    quarterIndex++;
    if(4 == quarterIndex) {
        quarterIndex = 0;
        year++;
    }
} while(reference < options.untilDate);
```